# Serialize fails in IE with new html5 form attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, serialization

For some reason, serialize returns an empty string on forms I try to serialize.

Two identical forms, one with the new html5 form attribute:

```
<form id="foo"></form>
<input form="foo" type="text" placeholder="cat" value="cat" name="cat" id="cat" />

<form id="bar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="dog" value="dog" name="dog" id="dog" />
</form>
```

Running serialize on both of these and one returns correctly and the new html5 form returns an empty string.

I'm hoping I'm doing something silly because this is a major issue for me as I don't have control over how these forms are written. I only have javascript hooks with this CMS I'm using.

Serializing with:

```
console.log($('form#foo').serialize());
console.log($('form#bar').serialize());
```

This works fine with every other browser I have tested, but not in ie, 8,9,10 or 11!

**EDIT:** I have just checked: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp, and the support for IE is not there... Has anyone found a hack for this?

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/875dks8c/5/

Comment: In your test, you close the first form right after opening it, and the input is out of the form. Maybe that's just your problem.

Comment: @Volune that is how the new html5 forms work....

Comment: @ShannonHochkins There is no reference to a form working that way over here.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form. Do you have any docs for your claim?

Comment: Well then maybe you forgot the ```form="foo"``` ?

Comment: Sorry, my demo html was wrong, but the issue is still there even with the correct markup, please see my updated demo. @Volune

Comment: I read the w3schools post you linked it.  A) That site is a terrible reference site and b) nowhere does it suggest having an EMPTY form element with the input element outside of it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_form

It doesn't matter whats inside the form. As long as the IDs are matched. Remove the input from the wrapped form on this demo and ress supmit in chrome, it still serializes correctly. @JeremyJStarcher

Comment: better yet, run my example in chrome or any browser other than IE and have a look at the output, it serializes just fine. @JeremyJStarcher

Comment: @ShannonHochkins—Posting code elsewhere is not liked. W3Schools is not a suitable reference for IE (or anything really), MSDN is.

Comment: how is it invalid? @RobG

Answer (score 1):

Fix with jQuery:

Rather than the more traditional serialize on an entire form. According to jQuery you can serialize individual form elements to. So with that, I found the [input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). From there, all I had to do then was use the form id as part of the selector and everything works great.

```
$(':input[form="foo"]').serialize();
// returns cat=cat
```

Tested: ie8-11

Comment: To be more generic, you can use `'[form="foo"]'` so other form control types are included. However, it collects only those with a matching form attribute, other successful controls within the form are ignored (and works with *querySelectorAll*).

Comment: :input matches all form elements that can be serialized, it's just a poor choice of name by jquery @RobG

Comment: Weird, but doing it that way means all form controls must have a matching *form* attribute, even those in the form, but it will not collect buttons. It also collects *all* controls with a matching *form* attribute (other than buttons), including ones that can't be serialised (e.g. ones without a name or value).

Comment: Yeah that's fine, that's how my forms are generated, and I digest everything accordingly

Answer (score 0):

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) does not confirm the compatibility with IE, and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535260(v=vs.85).aspx) does not reference the form attribute on inputs.

So I guess IE does not yet support this attribute, and you'll have to wait (and hope) an implementation in IE12, or do not depend on this attribute.

Comment: I have found a fix for this, please see my answer.